# How to differentiate formulas that have matrices as variables

Tags: matrices, derivatives, euler-lagrange-equation, transpose

I have this formula where $x,Q, b$ and $\lambda$ are matrices...

$\frac 12 x^TQx-\lambda^T(Ax-b)$.

I need to differentiate this equation with respect to $x$. I have multiplied it all out and I get this...

$\frac 12 x^TQx-\lambda^TAx-\lambda^Tb$

When I differentiate it I get...

$\frac 12 Qx-\lambda^TA$  ($x^Tx = x^2$ and $\frac 12x^2$ differentiated is just $x$).

but, according to the solutions, it should be...

$\frac 12 Qx-\lambda A^T$. I don't understand why the transpose is in the A and not the lambda.

Comment: I agree. But I'm also confused about $\frac12 Qx$. Is it said that $Q$ is symmetric, i.e. $Q^T = Q$?

Comment: It isn't stated but I'm fairly sure it is symmetric. It also only has positive eigenvalues.

Comment: Then probably they have transposed the derivative.

Comment: Both your answer and the solution you read are wrong. Call your function $f$. When $Q$ is symmetric and $f$ is a real-valued function, the **derivative** of $f$ at $x_0$ should be the linear **function** $Df(x_0):x\mapsto x_0^TQx-\lambda^TAx$, the **Jacobian matrix** is $J(x_0)=x_0^TQ-\lambda^TA$ and the **gradient vector** is $\nabla f(x_0)=J(x_0)^T=Qx_0-A^T\lambda$. I know that some people just call the Jacobian matrix or the gradient as the "derivative", but even so, your answer and the reference solution are wrong. (The matrix dimensions do not match in the first place.)